# How do I algebraically express that I'm using the integer part of a real number?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to elaborate an answer and I need to display that from real number (e.g. 1.236) the answer would be just the integer part (e.g. 1), how would I do that, there is something like $abs()$, but for integers?

Answer (score 3):

The floor function (denoted $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$) does precisely what you are looking for:

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer $n$ such that $n\leq x$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Zignd: That would give you (for example) $\lfloor-5.2\rfloor=-6$. Are you sure it's what you want?

Comment: The observation of @barakmanos is useful to introduce also the ceiling function (denoted $\lceil\cdot\rceil$). For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it is defined: $\lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer not larger than $x$. In particular $\lceil -d.d_0d_1..d_n \rceil = -d$ (here I use the decimal notation, $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $d_i$ is an integer between $0$ and $9$).